# ASP.NET GridView/DetailView controls

Tags: asp.net, detailsview

I'm modifying someone's web app with a Gridview/DetailView control pair. Currently the user has to select a row in the GridView to expose the DetailView and then select NEW to insert a new record. I'd like to short cut this and expose the DetailView in INSERT mode without having to select a row in the Gridview first. Can it be done? I've tried triggering the ChangeMode event: DetailsView1.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Insert) but no success. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It can certainly be done, and quite simply.  Just set the DefaultMode property of the DetailsView control to Insert.  Read more about it at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.defaultmode.aspx

Comment: I guess I'm doing it wrong. When the page loads the gridview is visible with data loaded, details view is not, set to insert mode as suggested. I created an Add New button with the following code behind:<br />public void Add_New(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            DetailsView1.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Insert);

        }<br/> Clicking the button does not reveal the detailsview.

Comment: I gathered from your post that you want the DetailsView visible by default.  If it is visible and the DefaultMode is set to Insert, then you should see it rendered appropriately.  Of course, the DetailsView control needs to be bound to a data source of some type.  There should not be any need to call ChangeMode if the control is already in Insert mode.